# Error: arguments imply differing number of rows: 42, 15, Convert Dat to Data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to convert dat data to data frame by converting the data and applying xml functions to extract. However facing the error different number of rows. The attached data was first reduced from the dat and converted to string. As being a beginner to R any help will be highly appreciated

Data:

```
dat <- '<d2lm:d2LogicalModel extensionVersion="2.0" extensionName="NTIS Published Services" 
modelBaseVersion="2" xmlns:ns4="http://www.thalesgroup.com/NTIS/Datex2Extensions/1.0Beta1" 
xmlns:ns3="http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0/inrix" xmlns:d2lm="http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0"> 
<d2lm:exchange><d2lm:supplierIdentification><d2lm:country>gb</d2lm:country> 
<d2lm:nationalIdentifier>NTIS</d2lm:nationalIdentifier></d2lm:supplierIdentification></d2lm:exchange> 
<d2lm:payloadPublication xsi:type="d2lm:SituationPublication" lang="en" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><d2lm:feedType>Event Data</d2lm:feedType> 
<d2lm:publicationTime>2020-05-10T00:00:44.778+01:00</d2lm:publicationTime><d2lm:publicationCreator> 
<d2lm:country>gb</d2lm:country><d2lm:nationalIdentifier>NTIS</d2lm:nationalIdentifier> 
</d2lm:publicationCreator><d2lm:situation version="" id="2922904"><d2lm:headerInformation> 
<d2lm:areaOfInterest>national</d2lm:areaOfInterest> 
<d2lm:confidentiality>restrictedToAuthoritiesTrafficOperatorsAndPublishers</d2lm:confidentiality> 
<d2lm:informationStatus>real</d2lm:informationStatus></d2lm:headerInformation><d2lm:situationRecord 
xsi:type="d2lm:RoadOrCarriagewayOrLaneManagement" version="" id="2922904"> 
<d2lm:situationRecordCreationReference>UF-20-05-09-600215</d2lm:situationRecordCreationReference> 
<d2lm:situationRecordCreationTime>2020-05-09T21:04:28.000+01:00</d2lm:situationRecordCreationTime> 
<d2lm:situationRecordVersionTime>2020-05-10T00:00:39.677+01:00</d2lm:situationRecordVersionTime> 
<d2lm:probabilityOfOccurrence>certain</d2lm:probabilityOfOccurrence> 
<d2lm:severity>highest</d2lm:severity><d2lm:source> 
<d2lm:sourceIdentification>RCCs</d2lm:sourceIdentification><d2lm:sourceExtension> 
<d2lm:sourceSituation><d2lm:sourceSituationId>SL</d2lm:sourceSituationId> 
<d2lm:sourceSituationCreationTime>2020-05-09T20:48:00.000+01:00</d2lm:sourceSituationCreationTime> 
</d2lm:sourceSituation></d2lm:sourceExtension></d2lm:source><d2lm:validity> 
<d2lm:validityStatus>active</d2lm:validityStatus><d2lm:validityTimeSpecification> 
<d2lm:overallStartTime>2020-05-09T21:03:19.755+01:00</d2lm:overallStartTime> 
<d2lm:overallEndTime>2020-05-10T02:41:00.000+01:00</d2lm:overallEndTime> 
</d2lm:validityTimeSpecification></d2lm:validity><d2lm:impact> 
<d2lm:capacityRemaining>0.0</d2lm:capacityRemaining> 
<d2lm:numberOfLanesRestricted>0</d2lm:numberOfLanesRestricted> 
<d2lm:numberOfOperationalLanes>0</d2lm:numberOfOperationalLanes> 
<d2lm:originalNumberOfLanes>3</d2lm:originalNumberOfLanes> 
<d2lm:trafficConstrictionType>carriagewayBlocked</d2lm:trafficConstrictionType><d2lm:impactExtension> 
<d2lm:impactDetails><d2lm:changeInCapacity>-100.0</d2lm:changeInCapacity><d2lm:individualLanesStatus> 
<d2lm:individualLane><d2lm:laneIdentifier>hardShoulder</d2lm:laneIdentifier> 
<d2lm:laneStatus>closed</d2lm:laneStatus></d2lm:individualLane><d2lm:individualLane> 
<d2lm:laneIdentifier>lane1</d2lm:laneIdentifier><d2lm:laneStatus>closed</d2lm:laneStatus> 
</d2lm:individualLane><d2lm:individualLane><d2lm:laneIdentifier>lane2</d2lm:laneIdentifier> 
<d2lm:laneStatus>closed</d2lm:laneStatus></d2lm:individualLane><d2lm:individualLane> 
<d2lm:laneIdentifier>lane3</d2lm:laneIdentifier><d2lm:laneStatus>closed</d2lm:laneStatus> 
</d2lm:individualLane></d2lm:individualLanesStatus><d2lm:returnToNormalStatus> 
<d2lm:predictedTimeToClear>2020-05-10T02:41:03.536+01:00</d2lm:predictedTimeToClear> 
<d2lm:predictedReturnToProfile>2020-05-10T02:41:00.000+01:00</d2lm:predictedReturnToProfile> 
</d2lm:returnToNormalStatus></d2lm:impactDetails></d2lm:impactExtension></d2lm:impact> 
<d2lm:generalPublicComment><d2lm:comment><d2lm:values><d2lm:value>Traffic is being diverted via the 
exit and entry slips</d2lm:value></d2lm:values></d2lm:comment> 
<d2lm:commentType>internalNote</d2lm:commentType></d2lm:generalPublicComment> 
<d2lm:generalPublicComment><d2lm:comment><d2lm:values><d2lm:value>TYPE : GDP</d2lm:value>< 
<d2lm:value>Location : The M5 southbound at junction J27 </d2lm:value><d2lm:value>Reason : Road 
Management</d2lm:value><d2lm:value>Status : Currently Active</d2lm:value><d2lm:value>Time To Clear : 
The event is expected to clear between 02:30 and 02:45 on 10 May 2020</d2lm:value><d2lm:value>Return 
To Normal : Normal traffic conditions are expected between 02:30 and 02:45 on 10 May 
2020</d2lm:value><d2lm:value>Lanes Closed : All lanes are closed</d2lm:value></d2lm:values> 
</d2lm:comment></d2lm:generalPublicComment><d2lm:groupOfLocations 
xsi:type="d2lm:NonOrderedLocationGroupByList"><d2lm:locationContainedInGroup xsi:type="d2lm:Point"> 
<d2lm:locationForDisplay><d2lm:latitude>50.9196</d2lm:latitude> 
<d2lm:longitude>-3.3536696</d2lm:longitude></d2lm:locationForDisplay></d2lm:locationContainedInGroup> 
<d2lm:locationContainedInGroup xsi:type="d2lm:LocationByReference"><d2lm:predefinedLocationReference 
targetClass="PredefinedLocation" version="12.10" id="101002501"/></d2lm:locationContainedInGroup> 
</d2lm:groupOfLocations><d2lm:management><d2lm:lifeCycleManagement><d2lm:cancel>false</d2lm:cancel> 
<d2lm:end>false</d2lm:end></d2lm:lifeCycleManagement><d2lm:managementExtension> 
<d2lm:situationManagement> 
<d2lm:confirmedBy>RCCs</d2lm:confirmedBy><d2lm:areaTeamInvolved>Area 2</d2lm:areaTeamInvolved> 
<d2lm:rccInformation><d2lm:allocatedRcc>South West RCC</d2lm:allocatedRcc> 
<d2lm:rccSituationId>1004</d2lm:rccSituationId></d2lm:rccInformation><d2lm:emergencyServicesInvolved> 
<d2lm:emergencyServiceStatus><d2lm:serviceType>police</d2lm:serviceType> 
<d2lm:serviceStatus>attending</d2lm:serviceStatus></d2lm:emergencyServiceStatus> 
<d2lm:emergencyServiceStatus><d2lm:serviceType>fire</d2lm:serviceType> 
<d2lm:serviceStatus>none</d2lm:serviceStatus></d2lm:emergencyServiceStatus> 
<d2lm:emergencyServiceStatus> 
<d2lm:serviceType>ambulance</d2lm:serviceType><d2lm:serviceStatus>none</d2lm:serviceStatus> 
</d2lm:emergencyServiceStatus><d2lm:emergencyServiceStatus> 
<d2lm:serviceType>airAmbulance</d2lm:serviceType><d2lm:serviceStatus>none</d2lm:serviceStatus> 
</d2lm:emergencyServiceStatus></d2lm:emergencyServicesInvolved><d2lm:peopleAndVehiclesInvolved> 
<d2lm:totalNumberOfPeopleInvolved>0</d2lm:totalNumberOfPeopleInvolved> 
<d2lm:totalNumberOfVehiclesInvolved>0</d2lm:totalNumberOfVehiclesInvolved> 
<d2lm:groupOfVehiclesInvolved> 
<d2lm:numberOfVehicles>0</d2lm:numberOfVehicles><d2lm:vehicleCharacteristics> 
<d2lm:vehicleType>articulatedVehicle</d2lm:vehicleType></d2lm:vehicleCharacteristics> 
</d2lm:groupOfVehiclesInvolved><d2lm:groupOfVehiclesInvolved> 
<d2lm:numberOfVehicles>0</d2lm:numberOfVehicles><d2lm:vehicleCharacteristics> 
<d2lm:vehicleType>lorry</d2lm:vehicleType></d2lm:vehicleCharacteristics> 
</d2lm:groupOfVehiclesInvolved><d2lm:groupOfVehiclesInvolved> 
<d2lm:numberOfVehicles>0</d2lm:numberOfVehicles><d2lm:vehicleCharacteristics> 
<d2lm:vehicleType>car</d2lm:vehicleType></d2lm:vehicleCharacteristics> 
</d2lm:groupOfVehiclesInvolved><d2lm:groupOfVehiclesInvolved> 
<d2lm:numberOfVehicles>0</d2lm:numberOfVehicles><d2lm:vehicleCharacteristics> 
<d2lm:vehicleType>motorcycle</d2lm:vehicleType></d2lm:vehicleCharacteristics> 
</d2lm:groupOfVehiclesInvolved><d2lm:groupOfVehiclesInvolved> 
<d2lm:numberOfVehicles>0</d2lm:numberOfVehicles><d2lm:vehicleCharacteristics> 
<d2lm:vehicleType>other</d2lm:vehicleType></d2lm:vehicleCharacteristics> 
</d2lm:groupOfVehiclesInvolved><d2lm:groupOfVehiclesInvolved> 
<d2lm:numberOfVehicles>0</d2lm:numberOfVehicles> 
<d2lm:vehicleCharacteristics><d2lm:vehicleType>trailer</d2lm:vehicleType> 
</d2lm:vehicleCharacteristics></d2lm:groupOfVehiclesInvolved><d2lm:groupOfPeopleInvolved> 
<d2lm:numberOfPeople>0</d2lm:numberOfPeople><d2lm:injuryStatus>slightlyInjured</d2lm:injuryStatus> 
</d2lm:groupOfPeopleInvolved><d2lm:groupOfPeopleInvolved><d2lm:numberOfPeople>0</d2lm:numberOfPeople> 
<d2lm:injuryStatus>seriouslyInjured</d2lm:injuryStatus></d2lm:groupOfPeopleInvolved> 
</d2lm:peopleAndVehiclesInvolved></d2lm:situationManagement></d2lm:managementExtension> 
</d2lm:management> 
<d2lm:complianceOption>mandatory</d2lm:complianceOption> 
<d2lm:roadOrCarriagewayOrLaneManagementType>other</d2lm:roadOrCarriagewayOrLaneManagementType> 
</d2lm:situationRecord></d2lm:situation></d2lm:payloadPublication></d2lm:d2LogicalModel>

 '
```

Code So Far:

```
library(XML)
require(plyr)
library(stringr)

datDF <- data.frame(
tags = unlist(str_extract_all(dat, "<([^>]*)>(?=[^>]*</\\1>)")),
values = unlist(str_extract_all(dat, "(?<=<([^>]{1,100})>).*(?=</\\1>)"))
) 

datDF
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

All variables in a `data.frame` need to have the same length. `tags` and `values` differ in length. You can make them the same length by adding NAs to the shorter vector and then combine them:

```
library(XML)
require(plyr)
library(stringr)
library(xml2)


tags = unlist(str_extract_all(dat, "<([^>]*)>(?=[^>]*</\\1>)"))
values = unlist(str_extract_all(dat, "(?<=<([^>]{1,100})>).*(?=</\\1>)"))

values <- c(values, rep(NA, length(tags)-length(values)))


datDF <- data.frame(
  tags,
  values 
)
```

But I would be careful, because this assumes that you parsed the document correctly. I think this is not the case since the tag `roadOrCarriagewayOrLaneManagementType` is on the second-to-last line but the corresponding `value` "other" is on the last line of `value`.

Comment: Any other solution with this would also be very helpful. thanks